# Which machine learning model is best for a combination of numerical and categorical data?

Tags: machine-learning, python, keras, machine-learning-model, matlab

I want to develop a ML model which will allow my company to highlight employees which are at a risk of leaving the business, based on a variety of parameters such as performance, absence rates, location, age, team manager etc. We have a fairly diverse database of individuals who have already left the business, with values for each of the inputs which can be used to train the model. The output is a simple 1 or 0: based on all of the inputs, either an individual is 'at risk' or 'not at risk' of leaving, with no immediate requirement for any indication of the degree of risk.

I am somewhat of a ML newbie, but having researched the various types of ML models, I cannot find any specific information which relates to training models with datasets where there are combinations of numerical and categorical data. I have looked at examples of similar model requirements which have used k-NN and SVM models, but I cannot find definite clarification on how to approach this task. Worth noting that I code in python and matlab.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: my bet would be a CART, but various models, eg SVMs, ANNs have proven robust with mixed data

Answer (score 1):

There are some ML models which use both categorical and numerical data

- Decision trees(with bagging),
- Random forest(with bagging & random
  subspace)
- Naive Bayes(numeric by Gaussian distribution or kernel
  density estimation)
- KNN based approach
- Ensemble Techniques
- linear regression

Note: you can always use different encoding techniques to transform categorical data into numeric and vice versa based on the ML model you choose

Answer (score 1):

Even though virtually any supervised classification algorithm can be used when having categorical features by applying some encoding technique, my first thought is using [Catboost](https://catboost.ai), an algorithm specially designed just for handling categorical features without a necessary explicit preprocessing/encoding phase. In short this algorithm will use an adaptation of target encoding and you can check details here:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.09516

From Yandex docs:

> CatBoost is an algorithm for gradient boosting on decision trees. It is developed by Yandex researchers and engineers, and is used for search, recommendation systems, personal assistant, self-driving cars, weather prediction and many other tasks at Yandex and in other companies, including CERN, Cloudflare, Careem taxi. It is in open-source and can be used by anyone.